# Imagen desborda del div

Tags: javascript

Quiero colocar un div y dentro una imagen pero está última se desborda, cómo puedo hacer para que no se vea el contenido que se desborda del contenedor?

Comment: En css creo que es `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

Tomando el contenido de tu pregunta, especificamente el siguiente enunciado:

> que no se vea el contenido que se desborda del contenedor

Puedes utilizar la propiedad css [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) en el contenedor de tu imagen

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>Overflow Scroll<p/>
<div class="container scroll">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="https://static.remove.bg/sample-gallery/graphics/bird-thumbnail.jpg" alt="js" />
</div>

<p>Overflow Hidden<p/>
<div class="container hidden">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="https://static.remove.bg/sample-gallery/graphics/bird-thumbnail.jpg" alt="js" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Es facil al div asignale un ancho y un alto y a la imagen dale el width: 100% esto ara que la imagen siempre tome el tamaño del nodo padre.

```
  <div style="width: 200px" >
    <img width="100%" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5191399.jpg" alt="js" />
  </div>
```

Espero te haya servido. saludos